# Http get method showing json file not found

Tags: angular

I am totally new in angular 4 and trying to call web api httpGet method. I create a json file named student.json . When I run my code in console I can see below Error :

```
 http://localhost:4200/src/data/students.json 404 (Not Found)
```

My Code :

```
fetchData(){
    this.http.get("src/data/students.json").subscribe(
        (data)=>console.log(data)
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVDQ1.png)

What am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried accessing that URL in a browser?

Comment: Yes bro, Displaying an Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @GolamRabbi Then that is your problem, that file is not accessible over http.

Comment: Then it's not your code that's the problem. It's the URL.

Comment: You should try to put it inside the assets folder and try to access it from there

Comment: You need put the complete url and  after http request put .map(resp => resp.json()).subcribe((data)=>{...})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `ng build`, go to `dist` and notice your .json file is not there. 
This is the reason why it is not being served, the webpack bundle is not adding that data folder, thus the app cannot find your file.

One way to get this to work, is to place your data folder in the assets folder:
`src/assets/data/students.json`

Then if you run `ng build`, notice the assets are available now, and your `students.json` is available as well.

By doing that, then `ng serve` will get what you want. Keep in mind, the .get is relative from your component. So for example, if I had that code in `src/app/app.component.ts`, I'd tell it to go back one level to `src`, then enter `assets` and finally read `data/students.json`, having a relative path `../assets/data/students.json`

In the code, like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this._http.get('../assets/data/students.json').subscribe(
      (data)=>console.log(data.json())
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this is of help.

Note: I mention `ng build` here just to display that `src/data` is not available and why it is not working. You don't really need `ng build`, `ng serve` is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in your service

```
export class MyDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchData() {
    this.http.get('../assets/data/students.json').subscribe(
      (data)=>console.log(data)
    );
  }

}
```